R: ggplot distribution diagram with 'more than limit' bar and geom_vline
colleagues.
I am trying to build a distribution diagram that will satisfy the following conditions:

Shows percentage of the values lying in each bin.
Bin size is specified by user.
All the bars are phisically the same width (in pixels). Last bar is showing pecentage of values that lie beyond specified limit
There is a vertical intercept line that shows median value.

Problem:
In order to visualize everything that is 'more than limit' I have to make the x-axis discrete, otherwise the last bar can be literally endless, including all values from limit to maximum. But in order to put vertical intercept at specified point, x-axis should be continuous.
Any ideas how can I workaround it?
Code:
Here is code example:
data <- data.frame(value = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1000))
data$value <- round(data$value, digits = 0)

median_elapsed <- median(data$value)

bin_breaks <- c(seq(0, 
                    median_elapsed, 
                    length.out = 11), 
                Inf)

bin_labels <- c(seq(0, 
                    median_elapsed - (median_elapsed / 10), 
                    length.out = 10), 
                paste0("> ", median_elapsed)) 

data$bins <- cut(data$value, 
                 breaks = bin_breaks, 
                 labels = bin_labels, 
                 include.lowest = TRUE, 
                 right = FALSE) 

get_home_data_percent <- data %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage = count / sum(count) * 100)

ggplot(get_home_data_percent, aes(x = bins, y = percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", just = 0) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Elapsed Time", 
       y = "Percentage", 
       title = "Histogram of Elapsed Time") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

Illustration:
So here I have almost everything needed, but not the vertical line with median value, as the x-axis is discrete.


this is not a precise question. Soliciting people for ideas is not a good format. You need to state precisely what you want to achieve as a result.

I've stated that in the first sentence:
"I am trying to build a distribution diagram that will satisfy the following conditions"

It's not clear to me that you couldn't put bins on a continuous scale. (Although maybe we'd want some custom axis labeling here for the last bin to clarify its meaning...)
Here I calculate median for the geom_vline, and separately set a value for the top category that includes all values over that value.
med = median(data$value)
upper = 600 
bin_size = upper / 11


library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
data |>
  mutate(bin = if_else(value < upper,
                       value %/% bin_size * bin_size, upper)) |>
  summarize(n = n(), .by = bin) |>
  ggplot(aes(bin + bin_size/2, n / sum(n))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = med) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(bin_size),
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1))



The problem with this solution is that it always builds the chart around median and then draws vertical intercept on the border of the bin.
but it doesn't work if the sepcified limit is set to '500' (or to 300 or to whatever other number but 'median')

I guess I misunderstood your example. See edit that separates the median from the top bin limit.

That works. Magic.
So for the sake of those who will search for the answer in the future:

the trick is to prepare the bins and the quantity of values in each bin in advance
in order to do it, division with the whole is used and then multiplying on the same number; for example, if the bin width is 10 and the number is 37, then 37 %/% 10 = 3, 3*10 = 30. Graceful!
everything higher than defined border falls into the last interval.
in ggplot we are shifting bars so they are put in between labels.

the only remaining thing is to substitute the last label to ">". But that one DIY :)

The approach to the labels is to add the conditional ifelse and remove the last label and add '>' to the previous one:
labels = function(x) {ifelse(x == upper, paste0(">", scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)(x)), ifelse(x > upper, paste0(""), scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)(x)))}

...and i found the issue: if there are no values in the particular bin, then the bin will be omitted. It needs to be adjusted via:
all_bins <- data.frame(bin = seq(0, upper, by = bin_size));
data |>
mutate(bin = if_else(value < upper,
value %/% bin_size * bin_size, upper)) |>
summarize(n = n(), .by = bin) |>
right_join(all_bins, by = "bin") |>
mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))
@JonSpring would you mind updating your solution please?
